# Is possible to use utc+1 in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm currently trying to do a countdown clock for my app, but i want to use utc+1.

The problem is that i don't know if the way i use it in "UTC+1" is the correct way.

```
final hours = new DateTime.now().toUtc().hour;
final minutes = new DateTime.now().toUtc().minute;
final seconds = new DateTime.now().toUtc().second;
```

I'm curently using this.

```
final hours = new DateTime.now().add(Duration(hours: 1)).toUtc().hour;
final minutes = new DateTime.now().toUtc().minute;
final seconds = new DateTime.now().toUtc().second;
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  final now = DateTime.now().toUtc();
  print(now);

  final later = now.add(Duration(hours: 1));
  print(later);
}
```

should work.